# Possible Choices for Cofinality of $\aleph_n$ without Choice

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, axiom-of-choice

$\text{ZFC}$ proves that each $\aleph_{n}$ for $n\in \omega$ is a regular cardinal. But it seems without the Axiom of Choice there are many consistent possible choices for cofinality of such cardinals.

**Please introduce some references for any known consistency result with $\text{ZF}$ about possible cofinalities of $\{ \aleph_n\}_{n\in \omega}$.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some partial answers:

1) By a result of Gitik, all $\aleph_n$'s can have cofinality $\omega.$

2) the paper "Cofinality and measurability of the first three uncountable cardinals" by Apter,  Jackson and Löwe completely solves the problem for $\aleph_1, \aleph_2$ and $\aleph_3.$ The following is taken from their introduction:

"In this paper, we investigate all possible patterns of measurability and cofinality for [$\aleph_1, \aleph_2, \aleph_3$]. Combinatorially, there are exactly 60 such patterns of which 13 are impossible for trivial reasons (e.g., if $\aleph_1$ is singular, then $\aleph_2$ cannot have cofinality $\aleph_1$). In this paper, we prove that the remaining 47 patterns are all consistent relative to large cardinals.''

3) The following is appeared in Ioanna Dimitriou's PhD thesis:

**Theorem.** Assume V is a model of ZFC which contains $\omega-$many strongly compact cardinals. For any function $f: \omega \rightarrow 2$ there is a model of ZF in which $\aleph_{n+1}$ is regular if $f(n)=1$ and singular if $f(n)=0.$

Comment: Mohammad, Both cases are very interesting. The case (2) is really comprehensive and wonderful! I think what happens if we add $\aleph_{4}$ to their collection! Thanks for references.

Comment: Then there will be much more cases, and many of them are open.

Comment: For example, it is open whether we can have $4$ consecutive measurable cardinals in $\mathsf{ZF}$.

Answer (score 5):

Ioanna Dimitriou's [Ph.D. thesis](http://hss.ulb.uni-bonn.de/2012/2777/2777.htm) as well many papers by [Arthur Apter](http://faculty.baruch.cuny.edu/aapter/) would be a good start.

You may want to read the proof of the Feferman-Levy construction, there's a nice proof in Jech "The Axiom of Choice" as well Ioanna Dimitriou M.Sc. and Ph.D. theses. Also interesting is the results in

> Truss, John "**Models of set theory containing many perfect sets.**" *Ann. Math. Logic* **7** (1974), 197–219.

Also relevant are the results by Magidor that if $\operatorname{cf}(\omega_1)=\operatorname{cf}(\omega_2)=\omega$ then $0^\#$ exists (this can be found, I believe in Magidor's paper proving the covering lemma, but also in Jech "Set Theory" as an exercise for Chapter 18); and similar applications of the covering lemma which prove the necessity of large cardinals for some of the results. Related to that is Andres Caicedo's answer to my [very old] MSE question: [Consistency of $\operatorname{cf}(\omega_1)=\operatorname{cf}(\omega_2)=\omega$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54761/consistency-of-operatornamecf-omega-1-operatornamecf-omega-2-omega).

On the same breath, one should mention

> Busche, Daniel; Schindler, Ralf "**The strength of choiceless patterns of singular and weakly compact cardinals.**" *Ann. Pure Appl. Logic* **159** (2009), no. 1-2, 198–248.

Which also deals with the question of many singular $\aleph_n$'s and its consistency strength.

From these papers and their reference, I think one should be able to cover all the known material.

Comment: Thank you Asaf. Do large cardinal assumptions have a main role in these results? Is there a particular main open problem here?

Comment: Yes, see the last remark in Andres' linked answer.

Comment: You may also find some ZFC results in Ioanna's Ph.D. thesis on section 2.2.